# No resource found that matches the given name android studio

Tags: android

I don't have support library in my gradle, nor i used it anywhere in my app

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   // testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
```

so why is it not letting me build? and generating this values.xml for no reason? i have tried restarting android studio already

```
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Comment: post your style.xml

Comment: "nor i used it anywhere in my app" -- if you used the new-activity wizard (or the new-activity portion of the new-project wizard), then you used `appcompat-v7`. The generated code references it. In this case, it would be the custom theme -- look for a `res/values/styles.xml` file.

Comment: I actually followed your tutorial for removing the support repository @Mark

Answer (score 1):

uncomment this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
```

It used in our project keep refernce to android internal stuff to support pervious version with new features.

Comment: Actually, he had a point. I know it's not what you're looking for. But he's right.

Comment: @Cassie what happens dude.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti i already said i am not using the support library in my project. what is his point?

Comment: That's why I wrote "I know it's not what you're looking for". But he didn't say anything wrong. Just nothing usefull for you :)

Comment: the point is, Is it appropriate to be posted here? i'd rather not misguide people

Comment: @Cassie look here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7 and then please one more comment here for my position.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you create an new Project, it creates a new Theme under

```
res > value > styles.xml
```

that inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.
So, basically, you need to leave that import in your gradle file, or just remove your theme from the `style.xml`file and from yor `Manifest.xml` too

Comment: when i do that, or delete my styles.xml it opens r.java automatically

Comment: and adds a dot in my package name on the very top of the r.java

Comment: Because you perform a `Safe delete` which check if a file is used somewhere in your project. And of course it is. Just leave the import, where's the problem of using it? It's a light library

Comment: i did not perform a safe delete, i delete styles.xml first and then it opens r.java and error is "files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited" i didn't even touch the build folder

Comment: Restore your `style.xml` file. Go in the `Manifest.xml` file, under the `<activity>` tag, remove the `style="theTheme"`. Open your `style.xml` and leave it empty.

Comment: it's style or styles?